# Excel-like user input in python GUI applications

Tags: python, user-interface, input, spreadsheet

Does python have any library to let user enter input values in cells in application GUI?

I mean, I will copy 10 values from an excel sheet (A1:A10) end paste it into cells in python GUI, and application will accept those 10 values.

Comment: `wx.grid.Grid` in `wxpython`, maybe?

Comment: Does it accept the entered values in cells as user input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah. Copy and paste, select and set color, adjust col and row width/height. You name it, you get it. Haven't done it in many years and can't remember all the tricks. But it is quite easy to do in Boa Constructor, http://boa-constructor.sourceforge.net/. Also see this very helpful blog: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/18/wxpython-an-introduction-to-grids/. A real example that I wrote a few years back: http://sourceforge.net/projects/deday/

Comment: How well does wx grid handle large tables, like 7000x5000 cells with objects in them? will it run slow?

Comment: I think it should be reasonably fast. It basically comes down to set the values in each cell by `SetCellValue(Row_index, Col_index, String_Value_for_that_cell)` method. Maybe additionally, you also want firstly to check if the size of the current spreadsheet is big enough for the data. If not, use `AppendCols(Number_of_col_to_add)` and `AppendRows()` to make it so. The largest data set I have seem for mine is about 20*20000 and I don't remember have to wait for it to complete (on a 1st gen. Athlon X2). But, if the data set are so big, maybe spreadsheet is not a good way to visualize it. ;-p